# Android intent parameter FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TASK missing?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have just noticed that parameter FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TASK is no more available in the Android developer documentation:

I am just trying to do this:

removeCard.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TASK);
startActivity(removeCard);

I have already seen such a parameter in code found in Google but the Java compiler just tells me it does not exist.

I am only able to start the main activity with this parameter but I have to configure the manifest file to perform this:

android:launchMode = "singleTask"

And this does not work for activities other than main activities launched upon app start.

Does someone know why this parameter disappear for Intent ?

Regards,
Franz

Answer (score 5):

Ok so after having a look around, I managed to figure out that there is no such things as FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_INSTANCE, nor has there even been. This is because you are looking for values which can only be defined through the application's launch mode which is defined in the manifest. Only FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is available as an intent flag. Therefore if you want to make use of any of the singleTask, singleInstance, singleTop or standard launch modes, they must be defined in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.company.ActivityName"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
</activity>
```

See the launchMode section in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 1):

`android:launchMode = "singleTask"` should work for all activities when used correctly and are you sure you're not referring the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TASK` which is still present and appears to do what you are wanting.

> public static final int FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
>
> Since: API Level 1 If set, the activity will not be launched if it is
>   already running at the top of the history stack.

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP are not the same. I am trying to pass FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TASK as a parameter. I do not want to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP. But this parameter does not exist anymore in the Android documentation.

Comment: Try this: http://developer.android.com/search.html#q=FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TASK&t=0 and try the same with FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP. The first does not exist (anymore ?).

Comment: @user255607 I don't think google are able to deprecate something without publishing it, I would imagine it breaks all sorts of agreements they have. If you google this flag your question (translated and scraped) make up 95% of the content. Perhaps you saw it's use in some prototype code before release or the flag was private (even then it would probably show up). If you could find where you saw and it was part of published documentation google would probably be very interested.

Comment: Regardless, the question seems moot, it's not present in the documentation and thus shouldn't be utilized and if you need a way to emulate the behaviour then you should focus on that in the question

Answer (score 0):

No it is not missing. From developer docs......[Using Intent flags](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
>   Start the activity in a new task. If a task is already running for the activity you are now starting, that task is brought to the foreground with its last state restored and the activity receives the new intent in onNewIntent().
>   This produces the same behavior as the "singleTask" launchMode value, discussed in the previous section.

That means FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK do the same as Singletask do

Comment: have you tested its behaviour?? I found its behaviour totally opposite as written in official documentation of the android.